# current sensor on arduino inaccurate at zero Load

Tags: arduino, current, sensor

I am currently making a power meter and used a Current sensor (SCT013 30A/1V) from [yhdc.com](http://www.yhdc.com/en/product/320/). Every thing went fine especially the circuitry following the tutorial from ( https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks/ct-sensors-interface ). Am using an Arduino nano. and emon library to calculate for current.

my problem is at no load connected, even when no load wire is passing through the sensor, I get small jumpy values of readings of the manner below.

```
Irms: 0.04
Irms: 0.04 
Irms: 0.04
Irms: 0.06
Irms: 0.03
Irms: 0.06
Irms: 0.03
Irms: 0.07
Irms: 0.04
Irms: 0.03
Irms: 0.03
Irms: 0.06
Irms: 0.04
Irms: 0.04
```

I have double checked the hardware and there is no problem.

when a load is connected with a current draw of more than 0.07A, the readings are perfect and stable. I was able to get the below reading when I connected a 75W lamp, and the voltage is 240V.

```
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.31
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.32
Irms: 0.32
```

My code is as below.

```
#include "EmonLib.h"              // Include Emon Library
EnergyMonitor emon1;              // Create an instance

void setup()
{  
 Serial.begin(9600);


  emon1.current(0, 29);        // Current: input pin, calibration.
}

void loop()
{

   float r1=emon1.calcIrms(2000);
   Serial.print(" Irms: ");
   Serial.println(r1);



 }
```

I would like my meter to accurately measure even the smallest consumption of say a phone charging in a domestic setting.\ or the smallest energy saver bulb.

Does anyone have an idea why this I get this kind of noise and how to solve it?

Comment: Read the ADC input directly, see what values it returns.

Comment: @jippie - Input to ADC from the Current transformer is AC (according to OP's link). Reading ADC directly will produce multiple different values. Perhaps the EmonLib.h is doing some processing on the input value

Comment: @Marla I think the ADC values are in the quantization noise, it should probably be sufficient without post processing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - the fact that an "Arduino" is being used is irrelevant to the problem.  The fact that the Arduino is based on an ATmega328p has *some* relevance, but many (most?) MCUs would exhibit similar behavior.  Really though this is a question which is fundamentally about key **electronic design** issues, and the kind of thing that tends to get *insufficiently informed* responses if asked on the Arduino site.

Comment: @Chris: If this isn't about arduino, then why discredit your question and mention it.  Remember arduino isn't just a platform but a state of mind and desire to NOT learn the underlying details.  The question also mentions a "emon" library like we're just supposed to know what that is.  There is also a particular current sensor mentioned, but no datasheet, and no schematic showing how exactly things were wired up in this instance.  This is about the high levels of using arduino software, not about electronic details.

Comment: @Olin so, use your hard-earned reputation to close as too broad and move on with your life. Your behavior is abrasive and solves nothing. Instead of yelling at people who don't know how to formulate a question that is complete, close the question/spend 20 seconds teaching them, and you both will be happier. They get their question answered, and you get to sleep at night knowing that they will write a good question next time. I find it odd that you find the need to "wage a war" on those not as smart as you.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was due to noise coming from the PC (thru USB). I installed a LCD to print my results, used a decent power supply and disconnected the USB. after that most of noise was gone and my current dropped to 0.00 at no load.

Comment: Thanks @DanielP i will definately go back to that piece of problem and try to resolve with this update.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking at the quantization noise of the Analog to Digital converter. You can check this by checking what values the ADC spits out with a simple `analogRead(pin);` and I bet you'll see only that value change a couple counts up or down. This means that you are working at (or very close to) the best possible resolution for the current setup. You should probably just disregard the lowest digit.

You can improve your readings by changing the full scale range of the current clamp by increasing the 33 ohm burden resistor and change the parameters in the software accordingly, but that reduces the maximum current you can measure.

Comment: Yes @Jippie, i have confirmed the values at analog pin do jump a little and even pointing the EmonLib to this pin that is not even hooked to the sensor still reads the noisy small current. My sensor actually has an inbuilt burden resistor so let me dismantle it and try to use a different resistor....Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> [I] would like my meter to accurately measure even the smallest consumption of say a phone charging in a domestic setting. or the smallest energy saver bulb.

In that case, you need to pick a better sensor. The specifications for the one you have are only guaranteed over a range of 10% - 120% of the rated current. This would be power levels of 360 to 4000 W.

You also need to be able to do range switching of some sort. I don't know offhand what the resolution of an Arduino ADC is, but assuming 10 bits, you can only measure changes of 1 mV over a range of 0-1 V, which represents a change in load current of 30 mA, or 3.6 W @ 120 VAC.

In other words, if everything else was perfect, low-power loads are going to show up as 0 W, 3.6 W or 7.2 W, nothing in between. However, you also have to deal with real-world issues such as noise, offsets and nonlinearities, which are going to make your measurements pretty much useless at this level.

Comment: Thanks Dave, let me try getting a better Sensor try it and will let you know of the developments